# cannot set pixels to buffer image, incorrect sequence item type: B

Tags: python, scripting, image, gpu-module

I'm trying to run the script:

```
import bpy
import gpu
import time
WIDTH = 32
HEIGHT =32

offscreen = gpu.types.GPUOffScreen(WIDTH, HEIGHT)

image_name = "custom_img"
framebuffer = None
viewport_info = None
pixelBuffer = None

if not image_name in bpy.data.images:
    framebuffer_image = bpy.data.images.new(image_name , 32, 32, float_buffer=True)
else:
    framebuffer_image = bpy.data.images[image_name]

def draw():
    context = bpy.context
    scene = context.scene

    view_matrix = scene.camera.matrix_world.inverted()

    projection_matrix = scene.camera.calc_matrix_camera(
        context.evaluated_depsgraph_get(), x=WIDTH, y=HEIGHT)

    offscreen.draw_view3d(
        scene,
        context.view_layer,
        context.space_data,
        context.region,
        view_matrix,
        projection_matrix)

    framebuffer_image.scale(WIDTH, HEIGHT)

    pixelBuffer =offscreen.texture_color.read() 

    pixelBuffer.dimensions = WIDTH * HEIGHT * 4
    framebuffer_image.pixels.foreach_set(pixelBuffer)

    framebuffer_image.filepath_raw = "/.../MyImage.png"
    framebuffer_image.save()

bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw, (), 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')
```

but it gives this error

> line 42, in draw
> TypeError: incorrect sequence item type: B

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution!
The buffer in `pixelBuffer = offscreen.texture_color.read()`
was of `UBYTE`, where as it should have been `FLOAT`

So I changed

```
offscreen = gpu.types.GPUOffScreen(WIDTH, HEIGHT,format="RGBA32F")
```